# dynamic rectangular or square div of any size which can be fitted into a fixed size div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change shape of a div by changing its width and height, his width and height may be a 3000*5000 but it can be shown in a 400*400 div... if you want to show the example of the same type then visit https://konfigurator.stylegreen.de/dimensions?language=EN and **go to the (dimension tab) 3rd form tab by choosing one of them..** and type any number in width and height it will be shown in a certain area..

Comment: With JavaScript, set up onChange event of two inputs, and use those values to set the div width/height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all about `ratio`. You need to calculate the ratio between the `rectange width` & `frame width`.

**Sample code here..**

```js
function renderBox() {

  const width = document.getElementById('width').value;
  const height = document.getElementById('height').value;
  const box = document.getElementById('box');
  
  let scale = 1;
  
  while(true) {
      if (width <= (400 * scale) && height <= (200 * scale)) {
      break;
      }
      scale++;  
  }
  
  box.style.width = width / (400 * scale) * 100 + '%';
  box.style.height = height / (200 * scale) * 100 + '%';
  
  document.getElementById('top').innerText = (200 * scale) + "px";
  document.getElementById('end').innerText = (400 * scale) + "px";
  
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}

.frame {
  background-color:rgb(200,200,200);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.scale #start {
  float:left;
}

.scale #end {
  float:right;
}

.scale #top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10px;
}

#box {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  transform:translateY(-100%);
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
 <div class='frame'>
    <div id='box'></div>
 </div>
 <div class='scale'>
    <span id='top'>200px</span>
    <span id='start'>0px</span>
    <span id='end'>400px</span>
 </div>
</div>

<br><br>

width: <input type='number' id='width'> <br><br>
height: <input type='number' id='height'> <br><Br>
<button onclick='renderBox()'>Render</button>
```